# Why does range in Python increments by 1 in the loop when performing calculation?

Tags: python

My Y[], Y1[] both have `range(0, 8736)`. When running the code below, why does the range extend by 1 to `range(0, 8737)`?

```py
diff = []

for i in range(len(Y)):
    if(Y[i]==0):
        diff.append(1)
    if(Y1[i]==0):
        diff.append(1)
    else:
        var = Y[i] / Y1[i] 
        diff.append(var)

print(range(len(diff)))
```

Comment: Maybe you meant the second `if` to be `elif`.

Comment: If `Y[i]` and `Y1[i]` are both zero, you append to `diff` twice.

Comment: @JohnGordon only `Y[i] == 0` matters, it appends twice even if `Y1[i] != 0`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand your question.

Comment: Incidentally you could probably use something like `diff = [1 if (y == 0 or y1 == 0) else y / y1 for y, y1 in zip(Y, Y1)]`. No need to deal with indices and other weirdnesses.

Comment: Do you really want to append `1` instead of `0` if the numerator is 0? 0 divided by non-zero `x` isn't  problem mathematically, but evaluates to 0.

Comment: @Masklinn Good point!

Comment: Its a prediction calculation. 1 means just use value from previous year so its the same number. 0 is problematic in further code where it gives a floating point divided by zero error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `i = 0` you append `1` twice, therefore `len(diff) = len(Y) + 1 = len(Y1) + 1`

Comment: Good catch!, should have used elif there or an OR in between. It appends 1 somewhere twice!